# Make a private C++ function visible to Qml

Tags: qt, qml, public, private-members

I have been making my C++ functions callable from Qml by following the approach given in [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html).

This require one of these conditions to be fulfilled :

1. Make the C++ function `public` and `Q_INVOKABLE`
   or
2. Make the C++ function a `public slot`

This sometimes is not in sync with my class design. As in, the function which I want to be callable from Qml, is private according to my class design.

Q1. Can I make a function visible to Qml and still keep it private ?

Q2. Is it my design flaw to expect this kind of behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you do something *private by design* you consider that it's something to be used only within a class. Now you are now asking actually is how can I workaround my design. Obvious answer is - you can make a public wrapper in a class which will invoke your private method and publish this public wrapper into QML, but I would suggest to review design if you face such situation.